# How can I use `https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf` in a Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I like to use `https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf` in a project.

Up to now I use `https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image` (https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image is requierd in https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf)

like this

```
window.print = function () {
    return domtoimage.toPng(document.body)
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = map.printControl.options.documentTitle || "exportedMap" + '.png';
            link.href = dataUrl;
            link.click();
        });
};
```

https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf does not offer a JavaScript File that I can integrate in my HTML-Document. That is why I create a JavaScript File myself with `https://github.com/browserify/browserify`.

1. I installed `browserify` global
2. I cloned the repo `https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf`
3. I run `browserify index.js -o bundle.js`

Now I have the JavaScript File and I use it in my HTML-File:

```
<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

It is correcly loaded. But I do not know how I to use it in my project.

I tried:

```
window.print = function () {
    return domtoimage.toPng(document.body)
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = map.printControl.options.documentTitle || "exportedMap" + '.png';
            link.href = dataUrl;
            link.click();
        });
}
```

and

```
var element = document.getElementById('test');
var options = {
    filename: 'test.pdf'
};
domToPdf(element, options, function () {
    console.log('done');
});
```

In the first case (domtoimage is required in domtopdf) I get the error `ReferenceError: domtoimage is not defined` and in the second case `ReferenceError: domToPdf is not defined`

How can I use `https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf` in a Browser?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use npm to install these packages? Could I see your imports and/or require statements...

Comment: It could also be that you use toPng instead of domToPng

Comment: I use it in a HTML Website.
I cloned https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf
and in this repository I created the bundle.js. After that I  copied it to my website and used <script src="./bundle.js"></script>

Comment: Yes I did use npm to install the package and after that I installed browserify and created the bundle.js
Now I want to use it in a HTML page in browser.
Here is the bundle.js: https://github.com/astridx/dom-to-pdf/blob/javascriptexport_browserify/bundle.js